# Passing HttpContext to Task.Run thread

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to pass `HttpContext.Current` to the thread created via `Task.Run`. As I have a Transaction ID in in `HttpContext.Items`, which I'll need in the thread.

```
public static Task<TResult> RunWithContext<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;                        
    return Task.Run(()=> { RequestHelper.SaveHttpContextInThread(context); return function(); } );
}

public static void SaveHttpContextInThread(HttpContext context)
{
    Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(RequestHelper.THREAD_SLOT_NAME), context);
}


var response = TaskHelper.RunWithContext(() => _service.UpdateJob(jobjsonstring));
var jobData = JObject.Parse(response.Result); //Compiler error here
```

But a compiler error

> 'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
>   to 'string'

occurs in the last line.

Seems to be an issue with the way I'm returning from the anonymous method.

---

Update

It seems _service.UpdateJob was returning Task but I was expecting it to return Job object, Apologies.

Actual Problem: In a WebAPI we want to run some task in a new thread. There is a value TransactionID in HttpContext.Items. We want the newly created thread to be able to read TransactionID. The above approach was to pass the entire HttpContext to the new thread.

Comment: Try `var jobData = JObject.Parse(response.Result.ToString());`

Comment: What is the return type of _service.UpdateJob ?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre No error after adding ToString. But I'm trying to create RunWithContext which can replace Task.Run, with no other changes. Any possible way?

Comment: @rboe _service.UpdateJob returns a Job object.

Comment: @Baga - the response.Result.Result could contain the string.

Comment: @rboe yes you are right. but any way to make RunWithContext return Task<string> instead of Task<Task<string>>

Comment: `I'm trying to pass HttpContext.Current to the thread created via Task.Run.` Please don't. `HttpContext` is not thread-safe. `Task.Run` (the way you're using it) negatively impacts your app's scalability and provides no benefit. What's the **actual** problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary! I want a value (TransactionID) to be available throughout the Web API request.

Comment: @Baga: But why use `Task.Run` in the first place? Whatever problem you're solving, that's the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can get quite confusing with the nested use of tasks, especially without the use `async`/`await`.

The _`service.UpdateJob(jobjsonstring)` returns a `Task`. Therefore `Task.Run` which executes this function returns a `Task` object with a `Task` as result.

In order to get the Result of the _`service.UpdateJob` call you have to use `response.Result.Result`.

```
 var jobData = JObject.Parse(response.Result.Result);
```

Another alternative (without async/await) is to return the Result inside the function, e.g.

```
var response = TaskHelper.RunWithContext(() => _service.UpdateJob(jobjsonstring).Result);
```

Comment: Thanks @rboe ! but any way to make RunWithContext return Task<string> instead of Task<Task<string>>

Comment: @Baga - I've updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: It seems _service.UpdateJob was returning Task<string> but I was expecting it to return Job object. My bad, sorry. Thanks!